# faking xmlhttprequests with casperjs

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, sinon, casperjs

I'm writing end-to-end tests with casperjs and would like to fake ajax server responses

I've came up with the idea of including a simple script that mocks the xmlhttprequest object and would always return my expected results, like the following

```
var ajax_requests = [
    ['GET', '/jobs', JSON.stringify(jobs)]
], stubs = stubs || {};

function setup_ajax(){
    stubs.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    _.each(ajax_requests, function(r){ 
        //r[1] = "http://localhost:8000" + r[1]
        r[2] = [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, r[2]]
        stubs.server.respondWith.apply(stubs.server, r)
    })
    stubs.server.autoRespond = true;
    stubs.server.autoRespondAfter = 2;
}
```

Then I call `setup_ajax` in my casper test like

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(setup_ajax)
}
```

but seemingly future ajax requests still avoid my xmlhttprequest implementation.

I've tried running setup_ajax on the fly, using $.ready() and having it called from casper too, but neither of these worked

More interestingly, checking for objects' existence strangely fails.

```
function setup_ajax(){
    return typeof(sinon)
}

casper.then(function(){
    var x = this.evaluate(setup_ajax)
    casper.log(x) // logs 'null'
}
```

But sinon is properly included, at least casper did not cause any errors when I've made some calls to it outside the setup_ajax function, but caused error when I deliberately had sinon excluded.

Do you have any ideas on mocking xmlhttprequests under casperjs?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) to fake XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: exactly that's what I try to use, could you give a more detailed description of how you would do it, please, as my approach (outlined above) does not work

Comment: Actually, this is my casperjs command:
$ casperjs test --direct --log-level=debug --includes=public/js/libs/jquery.js,public/js/libs/underscore-min.js,test/stubs/sinon-1.3.4.js,test/stubs/ajax_requests.js test/frontend/jobs.js

You can see how libs are supposed to be included.

Comment: The `--includes` cli parameter doesn't accept client-side targeted libraries; it's only intended to provide a convenient way to load common scripts to be used in the phantomjs environment - not in the remote DOM one. (hint: I'm the author of casperjs)

Comment: I know that you are the author, and I'm thankful for your kind support. Thanks for clarifying this out.

Answer (score 1):

[PhantomXHR](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomXHR) wraps the XHR mocking of SinonJS for casperjs.

First you need to initialize PhantomXHR:

```
var xhr = require('phantomxhr');
casper.on('page.initialized', function () {
    xhr.init(casper.page, {
        libraryRoot: '/path/to/node_modules/phantomxhr/'
    });
});
```

Than you can fake the XHR request:

```
var fake = xhr.fake({
    url: '/jobs',
    responseBody: jobs
});
```

Take care of waiting for the XHR request to finish before evaluating the page. You can check if the request completed by looking for

```
fake.count() === 1
```